# Finding the normal stress of using rotated stress tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors, rotations

I wish to find the normal stress at the point on an interface whose normal unit vector is

$$n=
\begin{bmatrix}
  0.6 & 0.8 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

given the stress tensor  $$\tau_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
  2000 & 500 & -1000\\
  500 & 3000 & 3000\\
  -1000 & 3000 & -4000\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

my goal is to rotate the stress tensor so the rotated $x$ axis ($x'$) is coalesces with the normal vector $n$ such that the new rotated $\tau_{x'x'}$ should be the answer.

We have that

$$\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac{0.8}{0.6}\right)=53.13 $$ using the rotatin matrix about the $Z$ axis $$R_z=\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(53.13) & -\sin(53.13)& 0\\
  \sin(53.13) & \cos(53.13)& 0\\
  0& 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

the rotated tensor is:
$$\tau_{i'j'}=R\tau_{ij}R^T=\\
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(53.13) & -\sin(53.13)& 0\\
  \sin(53.13) & \cos(53.13)& 0\\
  0& 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  2000 & 500 & -1000\\
  500 & 3000 & 3000\\
  -1000 & 3000 & -4000\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(53.13) & \sin(53.13)& 0\\
  -\sin(53.13) & \cos(53.13)& 0\\
  0& 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}
  2160 & -620 & -3000\\
  -620 & 2840 & 1000\\
  -3000 & 1000 & -4000\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

which yields **a wrong answer**: $\tau_{x'x'}=2160$.

But $\tau_{\textbf{i'j'}}=R^T\tau_{ij}R$ yields the correct answer:

$$\tau_{\textbf{i'j'}}=\\
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(53.13) & \sin(53.13)& 0\\
  -\sin(53.13) & \cos(53.13)& 0\\
  0& 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  2000 & 500 & -1000\\
  500 & 3000 & 3000\\
  -1000 & 3000 & -4000\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(53.13) & -\sin(53.13)& 0\\
  \sin(53.13) & \cos(53.13)& 0\\
  0& 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
=\begin{bmatrix}
  3120 & 340 & 1800\\
  340 & 1880 & 2600\\
  1800 & 2600 & -4000\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\tau_{\textbf{i'j'}}=\tau_{x'x'}=3120$.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\t{\theta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\v#1{\begin{Bmatrix}#1\end{Bmatrix}}
\def\mbrace#1{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right\rbrace}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Given
$$\eqalign{
T = \m{
2000 & 500 & -1000 \\
500 & 3000 & 3000 \\
-1000 & 3000 & -4000 \\
}\qquad 
n = \m{0.6\\0.8\\0.0}
\\
}$$
You are looking for the rotation which rotates the first basis vector
$\{e_1\}$ into the $n$ direction.

So the **first** column of $R$ is given by $Re_1=n\:$
and the remaining columns can be determined using orthogonality and symmetry considerations, without any trig calculations
$$\eqalign{
R = \m{
0.6 & -0.8 & \;0.0 \\
0.8 &  0.6 & \;0.0 \\
0.0 &  0.0 & \;1.0 \\
}
}$$
Now do the required stress calculation
$$\eqalign{
\sigma
 &= n^TTn \;=\; \c{3120} \\
 &= \LR{Re_1}^TT\LR{Re_1} \\
 &= e_1^T\LR{R^TTR}e_1 \\
}$$
The rotated stress tensor (in parentheses) is
$$\eqalign{
T' = R^TTR = \m{
\c{3120} & 340 & 1800 \\
340 & 1880 & 2600 \\
1800 & 2600 & -4000 \\}
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrix $R_z$ represents the change from the new basis $\mathbb B$' to the old one $\mathbb B$, therefore

$$R_z\,T'=\tau \; R_z\,n' \implies T'=R_z^T\,\tau \, R_z\,n'$$

then in the new basis $\tau'=R_z^T\,\tau \, R_z$.

Refer also to

- [Changing the basis of a linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2779771/505767)

---

The key point is that matrix $R_z$ represents the change from the new basis $\mathbb B$' to the old one $\mathbb B$, indeed in the new basis the normal vector is $n'=[1\;\;0\;\;0]$ and then

$$R_z\,n' = n=[0.60\;\; 0.80\;\;0]$$

which is indeed the normal vector in the old basis.

Comment: @Monster Maybe I've solved the doubt. We have that $T_n = \tau \;n=(1600,2700,1800)$ and $\sigma_n = T_n\; n = 3120$

Comment: @Monster $1600$ is indeed the component of $T_n$ wrt $x$ axes.

Comment: @Monster While, after rotation, $n'=e_1'$ and then $(T'_n\;n')n'=3120$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I also was a little bit confused on that! Thanks, Bye